# When binding a client TCP socket to a specific local port with Winsock, SO_REUSEADDR does not have any effect

Tags: c, winapi, sockets, tcp, winsock

I'm binding a *client* TCP socket to a specific local port. To handle the situation where the socket remains in `TIME_WAIT` state for some time, I use `setsockopt()` with `SO_REUSEADDR` on a socket.

It works on Linux, but does not work on Windows, I get `WSAEADDRINUSE` on `connect()` call when the previous connection is still in `TIME_WAIT`.

MSDN is not exactly clear what should happen with client sockets:

> [...] For server applications that need to bind multiple sockets to the same port number, consider using `setsockopt` (`SO_REUSEADDR`). Client applications usually need not call bind at all—connect chooses an unused port automatically. [...]

How do I avoid this?

Comment: Can you tell us why would you want to bind a client socket to a port?

Comment: @Jay it's a requirement of the external system I'm interfacing with, and is impossible to avoid.

Comment: can you share a working code piece for binding a client socket on Linux?

Comment: my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711608/linux-how-to-send-tcp-packet-from-specific-port

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you create a socket with `socket()`, it has only a type and a protocol family. The ideal is to `bind()` it to a local address:port too.

The error you mentioned normally happens when the last connection to the same host:port didn't have a graceful shutdown (FIN/ACK FIN/ACK). In these cases, the socket stays in `TIME_WAIT` state for a certain period of time (OS dependent, but adjustable).

What happens then is when you try to `connect()` to the same host and same port, it uses the default socket's name/address/port/etc, but this combination is already in use by your *zombie* socket. To avoid this, you can change the local address:port used to establish the connection by calling `bind()` after the socket creation, providing the `sockaddr` struct filled with your local address and a *random* port.

```
int main() {
    int ret, fd;
    struct sockaddr_in sa_dst;
    struct sockaddr_in sa_loc;
    char buffer[1024] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n";

    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // Local
    memset(&sa_loc, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    sa_loc.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa_loc.sin_port = htons(LOCAL_RANDOM_PORT);
    sa_loc.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS);

    ret = bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&sa_loc, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    assert(ret != -1);

    // Remote
    memset(&sa_dst, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    sa_dst.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa_dst.sin_port = htons(80);
    sa_dst.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("64.233.163.104"); // google :)

    ret = connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&sa_dst, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    assert(ret != -1);

    send(fd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
    recv(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    printf("%s\r\n", buffer);
}
```

**UPDATE**: As using a specific local port is a requirement, consider setting `SO_LINGER` with `l_onoff=1` and `l_linger=0` so your socket won't block upon `close`/`closesocket`, it will just  ignore queued data and (hopefully) close the fd. As a last resort you can adjust the `TIME_WAIT` delay by changing the value of this registry key (highly discouraged!):

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\TcpTimedWaitDelay
```

Comment: Yes, I know the mechanics behind it, but unfortunately, that's not an option for me. I *do* need to bind to the same local port every single time (see my comment to the question).

Comment: Btw, I've updated the last lines to mention SO_LINGER. It came to mind after @Len's comment.

Comment: It's just that adjusting TIME_WAIT on a machine wide basis should be one of the last things to think about... There's often a better way; such as moving the active close to the other side of the connection or using linger to send an RST...

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which Windows platform you're running on, that may affect things as may the security principal that you're running under (i.e. are you admin?)...

This may help: http://blogs.msdn.com/wndp/archive/2005/08/03/Anthony-Jones.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Be careful in binding the local port NOT to use the loopback address "127.0.0.1", or you will get connection timeouts.  Better not to populate the sa_loc.sin_addr.s_addr at all - that works just fine.