# Linux: how to send TCP packet from specific port?

Tags: linux, tcp

How to open a raw socket for sending from specific TCP port? I want to have all my connections always go from a range of ports below ephemerals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using *raw* sockets, then just fill in the correct TCP source port in the packet header.

If, instead, you are using the TCP socket interface (`socket()`, `connect()` and friends), then you can set the source port by calling the [`bind()`](http://www.scottklement.com/rpg/socktut/bindapi.html) system call for the client socket - exactly as you would to set the listening port for the server socket.

Comment: struct sockaddr_in {
short sin_family;
unsigned short sin_port; 
struct in_addr sin_addr; 
char sin_zero[8];
};  -- where to set the port?

Comment: @Erik, then I do bind(), and then sin_port is set to server's port, and then connect(), right?

Comment: that is correct. Out of curiosity, why do you want to work with raw sockets?

Answer (score 1):

Making a tcp connection using raw sockets is somewhere between difficult and impossible; you'd need to implement the entire tcp protocol in your program *AND* also stop the kernel from sending its own replies to the packets (if the kernel has IP bound on that address on that interface).

This is probably not what you want. However, if you did want it, it is trivial to send tcp frames with any source port you want, as you get to specify it in the tcp header, which of course, if you're implementing your own TCP layer, you'll need to understand.