# Set a static Client Port , TCPIP, .net

Tags: .net, winsock

### Situation

a server that expects client requests FROM a static port say all connections to the server MUST be from port 9005.

### Question

How do I connect from a client from the same port every time?

### OS and Environment

Windows 2008 Server, .NET, using Winsock

Comment: WinsockClient.LocalPort = "20000"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `bind` the local socket to the correct port, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605182/when-binding-a-client-tcp-socket-to-a-specific-local-port-with-winsock-so-reuse) in C.

Comment: Thanks fvu, I have decided to have a separate component in C to do this and use this component as a bridge between my .NET app and the remote server.