# Issue in establishing TCP connection from every node to every other node

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I have some `n` nodes and I want to connect them to each other via TCP. I am implementing the following pseudo-code :

```
Node ids in {1, 2, ..., n}
For node having node id k :
  act as the client and try to connect to nodes with id > k
  act as the server and listen for connection requests from nodes with id < k
    while tracking which of the nodes connected in each step
```

Both the steps in the pseudo-code are implemented as `for` loops. **Notably, all the tcp connections use the same port.** The code works for `2` nodes, but for `3` nodes, the second listen function at node with `id 3` (which is listening for a connection) prints the error **"Address already in use"**. I believe that the call to the accept() function returns an error.

I am programming (using sockets) in `C++` and `linux` (Ubuntu 15.04).

I searched online and concluded that more than two clients can connect to the same port (because the sockets will be different at the server). What am I doing wrong?

Edit :
The actual code (just a snippet of relevant functions). Assume `ip_addrs`, node_rank, num_nodes to be suitably initialized.

```
// port for the tcp connection
int port = 25551;
// ip address of the local node
string ip_addr;
// sockets for talking to the nodes
vector <int> sockets;

static int exchange_node_rank(int sock) {
    char msg[10];
    sprintf(msg, "%d", node_rank);
    write(sock, msg, sizeof(msg));
    read(sock, msg, sizeof(msg));
    int rank;
    sscanf(msg, "%d", &rank);
    return rank;
}

// servername is only for client, it *is* NULL for server
static pair<int, int> sock_connect(const char *servername) {
    struct addrinfo *resolved_addr = NULL;
    struct addrinfo *iterator;
    char service[6];
    int sockfd = -1;
    int listenfd = 0;
    int tmp;
    struct addrinfo hints = {.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE,
                             .ai_family = AF_INET,
                             .ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM};
    if(sprintf(service, "%d", port) < 0) goto sock_connect_exit;
    /* Resolve DNS address, use sockfd as temp storage */
    sockfd = getaddrinfo(servername, service, &hints, &resolved_addr);
    if(sockfd < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s for %s:%d\n", gai_strerror(sockfd), servername,
                port);
        goto sock_connect_exit;
    }
    /* Search through results and find the one we want */
    for(iterator = resolved_addr; iterator; iterator = iterator->ai_next) {
        sockfd = socket(iterator->ai_family, iterator->ai_socktype,
                        iterator->ai_protocol);
        if(sockfd >= 0) {
            if(servername) {
                /* Client mode.  Initiate connection to remote */
                while((tmp = connect(sockfd, iterator->ai_addr,
                                     iterator->ai_addrlen))) {
                }
            } else {
                /* Server mode.
           Set up listening socket an accept a connection */
                listenfd = sockfd;
                sockfd = -1;
                if(bind(listenfd, iterator->ai_addr, iterator->ai_addrlen))
                    goto sock_connect_exit;
                listen(listenfd, 1);
                sockfd = accept(listenfd, NULL, 0);
            }
        }
    }
sock_connect_exit:
    if(listenfd) close(listenfd);
    if(resolved_addr) freeaddrinfo(resolved_addr);
    if(sockfd < 0) {
        if(servername)
      fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't connect to %s:%d\n", servername, port);
        else {
            perror("server accept");
            fprintf(stderr, "accept() failed\n");
        }
    }
    int rank = exchange_node_rank(sockfd);
    return pair<int, int>(sockfd, rank);
}

void establish_tcp_connections (const vector <string> & ip_addrs) {
  // try to connect to nodes greater than node_rank
  for(int i = num_nodes - 1; i > node_rank; --i) {
    cout << "trying to connect to node rank " << i << endl;
    pair <int, int> p = sock_connect(ip_addrs[i].c_str());
    cout << "connected to node rank " << i << endl << endl;
    assert(p.second == i);
    // set the socket
    sockets[i] = p.first;
  }

  // listen to nodes trying to connect (having id less than node_rank).
  // make sure that the caller is correctly identified with its id!
  for(int i = node_rank - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    cout << "listening for nodes with lesser rank" << endl;
    pair <int, int> p = sock_connect((char *)NULL);
    cout << "connected to node rank " << p.second << endl << endl;
    assert(p.second < node_rank);
    // set the socket
    sockets[p.second] = p.first;
  }
}
```

Comment: we cant debug psuedo code. But it sounds like you are opening a listening port with the same port number. Only set up the listening port once

Comment: okay, I am editing the question and posting the actual code.

Comment: Are all nodes on different hosts ? Also, in the code you posted, the clients try to connect to the servers before they're started, and I don't see how this could work.

Comment: yes, different hosts. There is an infinite while loop in the connect function so that the server can be restarted later.

Comment: you dont seem to be spcifying the port number to listen on in your bind. YOu are simply passing the results of a host lookup. Look here for sample of setting up socket to lsiten http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605182/when-binding-a-client-tcp-socket-to-a-specific-local-port-with-winsock-so-reuse

Comment: As @pm100 says, for the receiving side, you need to call `listen` once and then `accept` multiple times on the listening socket (once for each inbound connection).

Comment: Thanks. Calling listen multiple times was the problem. I fixed it.